# Focus calibration to infinity

Tags: calibration

Well, it sounds easy problem but can we do it without pointing the camera to a faraway place?
How does the manufacturer do this during mass production? Is there any focusing machine?

Comment: use a corrective lens perhaps

Comment: you are right. I just put a magnifier in front of the lens and solved the problem.